# Code working properly in java, but same code failing in some Test Cases in C

Tags: java, c, algorithm, ascii, implementation

I was doing practice algorithms problems HackerRank website and I submitted my code firstly in C language but I got some Test Cases incorrect. I thought my logic was right so I ported my code to Java and I passed all my Test Cases.

**Link to the problem definition:**
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/caesar-cipher-1

**Here is my code in C:**

```
    int main(){
    int n; 
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char* s = (char *)malloc(n * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", s);
    int k; 
    scanf("%d", &k);
        k = k % 26;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(s[i] >= 65 && s[i] <= 90){
            s[i] += k;
            if(s[i] > 90){
                s[i] = s[i] - 90 + 64;
            }
        }
        if(s[i] >= 97 && s[i] <= 122){
            s[i] += k;
            if(s[i] > 122){
                s[i] = s[i] - 122 + 96;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

**And here is my code in Java:**

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String str = br.readLine();
        int K = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        K %= 26;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if(c >= 65 && c <= 90){
                c += K;
                if(c > 90){
                    c = (char)(c - 90 + 64);
                }
            }
            if(c >= 97 && c <= 122){
                c += K;
                if(c > 122){
                    c = (char)(c - 122 + 96);
                }
            }
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Both my solutions are passing Sample Test Cases and logic is all the same. I can't understand why it is showing W/A in C in some Test Cases.

P.S. This is practice problem solution and not a live contest solution.

Comment: You are not allocating memory for the input string null terminator...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you. Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C strings are terminated with a special `'\0'` character appended to their end. So an actual string is always `1` character longer than the visible text. 
You are not allocating memory for the input string null terminator:
Replace

```
char* s = (char *)malloc(n * sizeof(char));
```

with

```
char* s = malloc(n * sizeof(char) + 1);
```

or even

```
char* s = malloc(n + 1);
```

as `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`.

In addition there would be a problem with these lines:

```
if(s[i] >= 97 && s[i] <= 122){
            s[i] += k;
```

`s[i]` might be `122` and `k` might be very well greater than `5`. As `s[i]` is most likely signed `char` type, and it might overflow past the value of `127`, which is the maximum for signed `char`. And signed integer overflow has an *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And `s[n] = '\0';`

Comment: @JoopEggen Wouldn't `scanf` take care of it?

Comment: If so, why it is passing some of the test cases?

Comment: @VatsalSura it is causing an *undefined behavior*. It *might seem* to work sometimes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes if scanf read not more than n chars. You are right though.

Comment: I tried adding the line you mentioned, it is giving the same answers.

Comment: there is an additional problem Let me add it to the answer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. so nothing can be done to solve this with the same logic in C?

Comment: @VatsalSura Of course it can. You can work with `int` as a naive approach. Or you can have the right side of the expression to always evaluate to something that doesn't overflow the `char`, like in the second answer.

Answer (score -1):

[image]This one is working fine.

```
int main(){
    int n; 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char* s = (char *)malloc(10240 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s",s);
    int k; 
    scanf("%d",&k);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(s[i] >= 65 && s[i] <= 90){
            s[i] = (s[i]-'A'+k)%26 +'A';
        }
        if(s[i] >= 97 && s[i] <= 122){
            s[i] = (s[i]-'a'+k)%26 +'a';
        }
    }
    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Just updated contents of if blocks and malloc size.

Comment: Why `10240`? Why not `1000345`?

Comment: I didn't put that number there, it was put there by Hackerrank itself. Maybe because none of their test case exceeds that range.

Comment: Accepted this? Seriously?

Comment: Added screenshot, happy?